# inserting google calender event into my agenda without oath

Tags: javascript, rest, google-api, google-calendar-api

i am creating an agenda system that list and creates events in google calendar API,
i have successfully retrieved using the following code:

```
var mykey = 'your_api_key'; // typically like Gtg-rtZdsreUr_fLfhgPfgff
var calendarid = 'you_calendar_id'; // will look somewhat like 3ruy234vodf6hf4sdf5sd84f@group.calendar.google.com

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: encodeURI('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + calendarid+ '/events?key=' + mykey),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        //do whatever you want with each
    },
    error: function (response) {
        //tell that an error has occurred
    }
});
```

now i need to insert events and everything i can find requires oath and is mostly about saving an event on the users calendar while i just want it saved in my calendar. any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service account => https://developers.google.com/android/management/service-account

- Create a Service Account
- Create a Key for your service account (JSON should work)
- Provide access to the required calendar scopes for your service account

  - Go to https://admin.google.com/
  - Go to Security->API Controls -> Domain-wide Delegation
  - Add scopes, for example https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events
- When you call the API use the JSON (JWT => Json Web Token) file to authenticate

In the account where the calendar lives you have to provide permission to edit events from your calendar to the service account.

All the steps and code samples for HTTP/Rest using service account are here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest_1